# Entity Framework - Source control for database schemes and test data?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I'm generating my models with the Entity Framework Powertools - which keeps the models up to date nicely. However, how can I keep the actual DB scheme up to date? How about populating with test data? I feel like this should be covered somewhere already but Google has failed me.

Comment: Check out entity framework migrations.

Comment: ... And that's the keyword I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you are using the ["Database First"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878.aspx) approach, you can (within visual studio) create a ["Database Project"](http://datablazeit.wordpress.com/2012/11/12/visual-studio-2012-database-project-ssdt-project-folder-structure/) from your scheme.

Using the database project, you don't need to keep the Sql Managemenet Studio opened to maintain scheme **and you can configure deploy including loads of data with pre-deployment and post-deployment scripts**. I believe this is a simple, elegant and professional way to solve your problem.

The database project improved in Visual Studio 2012.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not an option for when I'm using MySQL. :)